# Proof for radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand formula for radius of convergence of complex power series $\sum_n c_nz^n$ from book of Raghvan Narsimhan.

(1) For every $r\ge 0$, consider sequence $\{|c_n|r^n\}$; suppose this is bounded  above by $M_r$.

(2) Define $R:=\sup\{r \,\,|\,\, r\ge 0 , \mbox{ and } \exists M_r\ge 0 \mbox{ s.t. } |c_n|r^n\le M_r \mbox{ for all } n\ge 0  \}$.

(3) If $|z|>R$ then we show that the series $\sum |c_n|z^n$ diverges.

(4) If $|z|<R$ then this series converges.

I am understanding steps (1) and (2). I arrived at following natural question:

**Q.** Is there any example of sequence $\{c_n\}$ such that *for any $r>0$*, the sequence $\{ |c_n|r^n\}$ is not bounded above.

---

The complete proof from the book[image] is below:

Comment: I think $c_n=n^n$ could work; am I right?

Comment: correct. Depending on the $r$ it could even be worse, e.g. if we have $c_n = n$ and $r = 1$ then $|c_n r^n| = n$ is not bounded above. Note $R$ is nonempty since $ 0 \in R$, but this might be the only value in $R$; this is what it means to have zero radius of convergence

Comment: Ok thanks; for $c_n=n$, if $0<r<1$, then $|c_nr^n|=|nr^n|$ and this is bounded above, am I right?

Comment: that is correct.